# A dead body was found buried near our Old House?

Tags: logical-deduction, situation, mystery

I lived in a very old house with my father a very long time ago . We are a family with $3$ members , and my mother had died long ago.

We have now shifted to a new house , since the old house became too old and we have decided to sell it at some point . Right now no one lives in the house .

One day I was watching the news when I saw that a dead body of a girl was found buried in the garden near our our old house !! . The police found the body and  said they will soon start to investigate .

I immediately called my father (who was living in another room) and we had the following conversation :-

> Me :- Are you watching the news?

> Father :- No, why what happened?

> Me :- A dead body was found buried near our old house we lived before !!

> Father :- What, are you serious? That's so scary . Who could have done that?

> Me :- Yes , it's very scary . It gives me the creeps when I think about it !

> Father :- Yeah it definitely does . I wonder who buried her near our house .

> Me :- The police are investigating about this case . I Hope they find the murderer soon .

> Father :- Yeah I hope so too.

For a second I wasn't aware of something . But now I immediately understood that my father is the killer and called the police, who arrested him very soon.

What made me think so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> He said "I wonder who buried ***her***..." How would he have known the victim's gender if he had not been the murderer?

Comment: That was quick !!

Comment: @SouradipDas - Yes, it was! My best yet, I think!